# variable-length lists in ksql

Tags: list, apache-kafka, ksqldb

In KSQL, one can use `EXTRACTJSONFIELD` for nested structures, but I don't see how to deal with variable-length lists. For example:

```
{"id":1,"quux":[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":4},{"x":5,"y":6}]}
```

I can deal with `quux` as a varchar for the basic stream,

```
create stream mystream (id bigint, quux varchar)
with (kafka_topic='mytopic', value_format='json')
```

but I'd like to be able to turn this into a table with:

```
quuxid x y
1      1 2
1      3 4
1      5 6
```

How do I deal with variable-length lists in KSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible in KSQL.

As you've seen, you can access the array data by index specifically: Populate test data:

```
echo '{"id":1,"quux":[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":4},{"x":5,"y":6}]}' | \
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t quux
```

Check message in KSQL:

```
ksql> print 'quux' from beginning;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1528791985250,"ROWKEY":"null","id":1,"quux":[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":4},{"x":5,"y":6}]}
```

Create stream:

```
create stream mystream (id bigint, quux varchar) \
with (kafka_topic='quux', value_format='json');
```

Query stream:

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'earliest' to 'earliest'
ksql>
ksql> select * from mystream;
1528791985250 | null | 1 | [{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":4},{"x":5,"y":6}]
```

Create stream with `array`:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM mystream2 (id bigint, quux array<varchar>) with (kafka_topic='quux', value_format='json');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
```

Access individual items by index:

```
ksql> SELECT quux[0], EXTRACTJSONFIELD(quux[0],'$.x') AS X, EXTRACTJSONFIELD(quux[0],'$.y') AS Y from mystream2;
{"x":1,"y":2} | 1 | 2
```

But you're looking for the equivalent of an `EXPLODE` function, which doesn't yet exist in KSQL.

Related github issues:

- https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1324
- https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/527
- https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1413 (which I've just seen you've logged, thank you :) )

Comment: I hadn't seen #527, it looks fairly relevant if not exactly what my #1413 suggests as well. I am not wholly surprised that it is not (yet) supported, I was hoping to find a gem or undocumented function. For now, I'll likely preprocess the stream (using python `json` module or similar) to explode it, though I am really enjoying learning the consistency/elegance of ksql. I'll hold off on accepting/awarding for a few, but I suspect that this will be the best I can get. Thanks for the effort and good working example.

Comment: @Robin Moffat, when I tried to convert the JSON array to primitive array in the stream, it gives me a deserialization error "cannot convert array to string".

Comment: @BharathParlapalli please start a new question with full details of what you're trying to do and example code & data.